# python tornado webserver + pywebview

Tags: webview, webserver, tornado

I am newbie at python. I tried several things to starting at first the tornado webserver and then should starting a webview (pywebview) with the url from the tornado webserver. 
Because I would like to put all together into an android app (used with buildozer) so that I am sure that with one click starts my tornado webserver+webview.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import webview

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    webview.create_window('Hello world', 'http://localhost:8888')
```

Server has started but no webview come up.
Maybe it is for me as beginner not easy to understand, maybe for an expert its 5 minutes to bring me to the right way.

Comment: Can you try by creating the webview before you start the `IOLoop`? Put the last line before `tornado.ioloop....` line and see if it works.

Comment: It starts the webview in a endless loop without any website and no tornado server. I read that the ioloop should be in a thread ... I will try and hope I get a result.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer this question, but I will for the people that are searching a solution for this.
You cannot use pywebwiew as webview. You should use Android Java webview .You can access it using pyjnius for accessing the webview class. It's hard to explain using words so you can see this project that uses this method: https://gitlab.com/damien.andre/minipy/-/tree/master
(The project is not mine)
EDIT: here there is official kivy tutorial https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser